# Reinstalling Ubuntu as main OS after removing dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, usb-installation

I installed Dual boot (Ubuntu and Windows), but then I decided to delete Ubuntu completely, and I did, I've been using Windows for a few months with no problems. Now I want to install only ubuntu, and use it as my main OS.

I have an USB with the ubuntu installation (I used rufus).
Now I'm trying to boot from the USB to install Ubuntu but in the GRUB there's no option to "Install Ubuntu", It shows the option to start from Ubuntu directly as if it was never removed (which I actually did, I deleted the partitions and everything).

Obviously if I try to start from the Ubuntu option then a black screen appears and my PC never starts (because I deleted it)

What is happening here? I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Select 'Ubuntu'. That will boot the installer that you remember.

Comment: If you see [something like this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUchS.png) then it is normal. Select **Ubuntu** the first option. If you get the black screen, then try again and this time select **Ubuntu (Safe Graphics)**, the second option. After that you will see [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9yCT.png) with a button for **Try Ubuntu** and another button for **Install Ubuntu**.

Comment: Are you booting from the USB?

Comment: Yes, I'm booting from the USB.
I tried selecting both options, "Ubuntu" and "Ubuntu safe graphics", and I only see a black screen, nothing happens.
I tried downloading the ubuntu iso and rufus again, still nothing.

Comment: Also Secure Boot is disabled, and CSM is enabled.

Comment: If UEFI system, do not enable CSM. And in Rufus create UEFI/gpt installer not CSM/BIOS installer.

Comment: Ok, I created rufus with GPT and non CSM, I disabled CSM in bios. Still not working. (Yes my PC has an UEFI system)

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem. If anyone is wondering this is what I did:
1- Disabled 'Launch CSM'
2- Disabled Fast Boot
3- Disabled Secure Boot Control
4- I saved all boot variables in a USB.
5- I deleted the PK Key
6- I inversed the boot option (first the USB with ubuntu, then windows)
7 -Installed the ubuntu iso with rufus, but I used GPT in partition, and UEFI in target.
8 -I selected Ubuntu(safe graphics) in grub, and replaced 'quiet splash' with nomodeset
Then it worked.
I have an Asus laptop with Nvidia.